# How to properly setup VMs for testing (personal test)

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, iscsi

So both of my testing VMs are on the same laptop and both of them are running Windows Server 2019 and both of them are on the same SSD.
Basically, I need to test performance when the SQL database is on iSCSI disk in LAN network while the SSMS is on the local disk.

When I setup the machines and set their network adapter as bridged (needed it for something else) and ping each other I get average of less than 1ms which is, of course not desireable.

The issue is that I don't have any other PC with SSD so I can't transfer VM to other PC.

How can I make it proper testing environment - when the latency is around 50,60ms or something like that so it acts like other PC in the LAN network? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you could manage cloud-based VMs running your application and test performance on top of appropriate hardware.

As for the latency, you could simulate its low bandwidth, high latency environment.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130354/how-do-i-simulate-a-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environment

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can. Hyper-V is not exactly a test environment - it is a production system.

Your best chance is not to bridge. Route. And put in a router VM that.... can do traffic shaping. Suddenly you can limit bandwidth. Not latency (that is highly problematic because it means the router/switch would need to cache everything for some time which may require a TON of memory, or would drop packets), but at least you can do traffic shaping.

This was discussed at MS some time ago:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/6abef4d6-62a7-4236-a95d-3968af830939/can-a-hyperv-machine-be-made-slower-andor-emulate-a-slow-network-connection?forum=virtualmachingmgrhyperv

same result - use a router. Though I would go with a Mikrotik, not a PfSense.